# npm link and node_modules folder

Tags: npm, node-modules

Maybe someone can help me with my current problem. Let's say I have an Angular (4) root application and a module that I want to integrate it. I develop them both localy and want to test them. One solution should be taht i npm link them...

I use 'npm link' in the modules folder (let us name the module 'module') and then go into the Angular Root application and execute 'npm link module'.

In my node_modules folder a symlink to the 'module' is created and everything looks fine...but when I look into it - the dependencies of the 'module' are not resolved. This meands that in the node_modules folder I can find the 'module' and in this folder I find again a node_modules folder which should not be (and webpack has really problems with it).

Do you have a solution for this problem - except manually deleting this node_modules folder and hopping that all dependcies are already resolved in the root application?

Thanks for every help!

Comment: did you found a solution for this problem?